# Java proper use of exceptions and cost

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm trying to take a slightly *stricter* approach to coding this class. Instead of my usual cowboy coding style, creating as I go, I'd like to first lay out the methods, the variables, the comments... all that jazz.

So now here is the concept of the exception.

Should I think "What are all the things that could possibly go wrong in this function?" and throw an exception for each (if existing ones aren't descriptive enough then create a new one)? It seems this is the most precise option.

Should the line of thinking be "These are things that will probably go wrong, I'll throw a general exception for everything else."

How about "Nothing will probably go wrong, I don't need to throw an exception, worse case I can throw a runtime exception in the off chance something does go wrong..."

What I'm worried about here is the performance of the error handing. Ideally I could imagine Java just converting those exceptions into nice little if statements or some sort of jump statement. I imagine this could only cost one operation or so.

I can also imagine Java creating a circus 20 calls deep for the sake of abstraction, maybe then they are costly and I should pretend I'm coding in C all over again?

I wrote the question in a silly way since its more fun for both of us that way, but its a serious question. I'm sure there is some balance, maybe a rule of thumb or ten. How do you think about exceptions?

**Edit:** I'm not suggesting I use exceptions for processing. What I am talking about is the number and preciseness of the exceptions (How specific an error, perhaps?).

Comment: Exceptions are costly, period. Exceptions are also exceptional, so the cost may not matter.

Comment: Exceptions are for exceptional cases. You shouldn't care much about the few nanoseconds they cost at runtime. Instead, you should care about making the code clear, maintainable, and easy to use.

Comment: Is there evidence to suggest that an exception only "costs" a few nanoseconds? Performance is a valid design concern.

Comment: Is there evidence to suggest that an exception has a cost so high to affect system performance? Remember the rule about optimization: never do it.

Comment: @pamphlet: if exceptions caused such a big performance problem, don't you think this problem would have been solved, or exceptions would be avoided by all the standard APIs?

Comment: That rule is not a rule.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the performance hit, unless you have measured that there is a problem.  I suggest you instead worry about making the code as clear and robust as possible and measure it later. BTW exceptions only incurr a cost when you trigger them, and a simple check which is rarely triggered can be optimised away with branch prediction in the CPU.

Comment: I don't understand this community/industry's obsession with ignoring performance. When you don't design for performance, it doesn't perform. Maybe it's fine for mickey mouse applications, but if you know you have to scale, why wouldn't you plan for it?

Comment: @pamphlet: I think you should read a little bit about the professional background of Peter Lawrey. His job is all about performance. So you got an expert's advice here. Designing for performance is fine. But using exceptions or not is the sort of micro-optimization that can ruin an API design without having any *significant* performance impact. Donald Knuth, another expert, said it: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @JBNizet I have no doubt that Peter is an excellent developer. I also have a career built on high performance application development. And one of the "tricks" I've learned is that ignoring performance leads to performance problems. I am just trying to offer another viewpoint, especially one that encourages people who are expressing interest in understanding the performance implications of their design choices. I apologize for being somewhat combative about it.

Comment: @JBNizet That Knuth quote is very frequently taken out of context. The  way it is carelessly tossed around an internalized by developers as gospel is exactly the attitude I'm trying to discourage. Your point about API design is a good one, and I also encourage thoughtful design in that regard. It's just frustrating to see people actively and routinely discouraging people from even thinking about performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions ARE more expensive at run time, so should not be used as a part of "normal" processing.

Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances. Anticipated failures should not generate an exception. For example a user providing invalid input (wrong password, invalid zip code, etc.) should not generate an exception.

Exceptions are for bugs, and serious unrecoverable system failures.

Note that JDBC's use of exceptions is poorly designed (according to the principles I'm suggesting).

Comment: In a stupid microbenchmark, I've just thrown and caught 100,000 exceptions in 100 milliseconds. What's the cost of a typical SQL query execution? What's the relative cost of a SQLException (which *is* exceptional) relative to the SQL request execution itself? The problem with SQLException is that they're checked exceptions, not that they are exceptions.